# Unable to Align the Views

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the part of the Code of a very long Layout.So posting of whole code was of no use.
  I want to align the **RED** circle.Both the positions are shown in the RED colored circles.
  The `ParentLayout` of whole activity is a `RelativeLayout` but has nothing to do with this.
  Please help me.I have tried all the things that I knew.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/texttitle"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/Layoutborder"
    >
        <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/Linearimagetop"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="3dip"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
          >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/productimage1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/defaultimage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/texttitle"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Availability "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="normal" />  
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/availibility"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="In Stock"
                android:textColor="#4A7023"
                android:textStyle="normal" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 3rd `LinearLayout` to :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="5dp" >
```

Not sure if you are satisfied with that kind of layout.

Comment: Hey,i have overlooked your Answer. Replacing that have done the trick.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided does not show where you have specified the properties of RED text "here". You could probably just add it as another element in your relative layout where you specify the availability and stock which would align it with the preceding text.

Edit: (after understanding your actual problem)

I would suggest wrapping in another linear layout which will enable you to position the text above the picture as shown in the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Availability "
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/availibility"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:text="In Stock"
            android:textColor="#4A7023"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texttitle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Linearimagetop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="3dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/productimage1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/texttitle"
                android:src="@drawable/button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I suspect what he meant is he wants the Availability | In Stock text to be moved to the location of the red 'Here' text, not have it as a new element.

Comment: You have done in a different Way which i can't use it as has certain constraints.But I have checked it in my Eclipse and it gives a closer Result So +1 for that.

Comment: could you elaborate on your constraints, maybe I can find a better solution.

Comment: To make it simple,i have a very big Layout with more complex design.To be simple,i don't want to import layouts that would make things difficult to Understand.See, i am not against your concept, but then, my precedents should not feel difficultly in understanding  my code.And,as the layout's position are dependent as I have positioned them relatively to each other.

Answer (score 1):

If this whole thing is inside a RelativeLayout, remove the outer LinearLayout (moving margins and such to the first child LinearLayout as required), and change the second child LinearLayout - the one with 5dp padding - to have

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

If you don't want to do this and have to keep the outer LinearLayout for some reason, move

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
```

from the parent LinearLayout to the first child, and set layout_width of the second child to fill_parent, and add android:gravity="right" to it.

Comment: Your Answer has not solved the problem but gave me some idea to solve it..so +1 to you also.

Answer (score 0):

This was the Another way achieve the above Output.Hope it may help SomeOne.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/Linearimagetop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/productimage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/defaultimage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/texttitle"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Availability "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="normal" />  
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/availibility"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="In Stock"
            android:textColor="#4A7023"
            android:textStyle="normal" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```